# Tax implication In India

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, india, dtaa

My husband arrived in USA (California) in Oct 2014 for the first time . For Year 2014 we were considered as non resident alien (for tax purpose I guess). We have filed for the income tax in USA and got refund of whatever taxes had been deducted from the income of Oct, Nov, Dec 2014.

My question is do we have to pay taxes in India for whatever income we have earned in USA in Oct to Dec 2014. If yes then do I have to pay income tax in india from Oct 2014 to Mar 2015 (as per your answers posted on other related queries) based on my US income. And if I am paying tax in India for the income of mentioned period then will I get tax relief in USA?

Answer (score 1):

The exact date when you went out of India matters. If you have spent more than 182 days in you are Resident Indian and the global income is taxable in India. So for the period of Oct-14 till 31 Mar 2015, the salary you have received in US will be taxable in India. Please consult a CA for specifics of you case. India and US have [DTAA](http://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/Pages/international-taxation/dtaa.aspx)